# Scrutinizer-ci configuring PHP Code Sniffer

Tags: continuous-integration, scrutinizer

Apparently there are two ways to configure scrutinizer-ci to use custom phpCodeSniffer standards. The documentation only mentions phpcs use in "build" node and it isn't clear if they do different things or if one is preferred over the other.

Docs reference: https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/tools/php/code-sniffer/

What's the difference between running the checks inside "build" or "checks"? Should I use both?

```
checks:
    php:
        custom_coding_standard:
            ruleset_path: 'ruleset.xml'    
build:
    tests:
        override:
            - 'phpcs-run --standard=ruleset.xml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official answer was to use `phpcs-run`.

```
build:
    tests:
        override:
            - 'phpcs-run --standard=ruleset.xml'
```

The `phpcs-run` wrapper retrieves the latest version of phpcs on every build. Otherwise a preinstalled version of it is used. So usually the best way of running phpcs is using the wrapper in the build section.